# Can I run code from a .NET assembly from a command line?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, assemblies

I have a .NET class library (as a .dll file) and that library contains a class with a static method. Is there a way to call that method from a command line?

Comment: do you mean that you want to use static function from command line as a command

Comment: @Devjosh: Yes, I want to create a .cmd file that would contain `magicallyCall MyAssembly.MyClass.DoStuff()` or something like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell/) is a guide on how to load a dll from Powershell and call methods in it.

The most important part of the post are these commands:

```
[C:\temp]
PS:25 > notepad MyMathLib.cs

(…)

[C:\temp]
PS:26 > csc /target:library MyMathLib.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler version 8.00.50727.42
for Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 2005 Framework version 2.0.50727
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2001-2005. All rights reserved.


[C:\temp]
PS:27 > [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(“c:\temp\MyMathLib.dll”)

GAC    Version        Location
—    ——-        ——–
False  v2.0.50727     c:\temp\MyMathLib.dll



[C:\temp]
PS:28 > [MyMathLib.Methods]::Sum(10, 2)
12

[C:\temp]
PS:29 > $mathInstance = new-object MyMathLib.Methods
Suggestion: An alias for New-Object is new

[C:\temp]
PS:30 > $mathInstance.Product(10, 2)
20
```

Comment: Much better link-find than mine. =)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look here, maybe?

http://blog.usepowershell.com/2009/03/exploring-the-net-framework-with-powershell-static-members-part-4/

And you can load your own assembly using

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(“c:\mysource\mylib.dll”)
```

If you're unable or unwilling to use Powershell, you need to wrap the call for your static method with a console application, as stated in [davecoulter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813557/can-i-run-code-from-a-net-assembly-from-a-command-line/6813578#6813578)

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- but you'll have to have a program with a `Main()` method that references that .dll and can call it-- say in a console application.