# Is 32-bit PowerShell always present on 64-bit Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: deployment, powershell, azure, 64-bit, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to use a 32-bit in-proc COM server from a 64-bit process on Windows 2008 R2. Hosting in a surrogate process is rather slow because I make lots of small calls and have huge marshalling overhead.

One thought would be to write a .NET assembly that uses that server, compile it as x86 and then [invoke via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6813557/57428). Clearly I need 32-bit PowerShell for that.

So far I looked at one installation of Windows 2008 R2 and looks like it has both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of PowerShell and so I can achieve what I want.

I'm not sure whether any installation of Windows 2008 R2, especially ones that are used as Windows Azure hosts, have both versions of PowerShell installed.

Are both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PowerShell always installed by default on 64-bit Windows 2008 R2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both instances are installed. Click the start button and type PowerShell, you should see 'Windows PowerShell (x86)' in the result. Both flavors are registered under different keys in the registery and don't share the same execution policy settings.