# aspnet_compiler in Azure starup task

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

Does anyone know if its possible to call aspnet_compiler from an azure role startup task to force a precompilation inplace. (And if so as a foregroudn/background or simple task?)

Perhaps something like:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_precompile.exe -v / -p "F:\siteroot\0"

Or are there any better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Your command is correct except for typo, should be sitesroot instead of siteroots.

Comment: Should also be aspnet_compiler.exe (instead of aspnet_precompile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work once you figure out the right path to the compiler although I haven't tried this specific approach.

An alternative I've tried is to use `ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication` as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620704/57428). I tried calling that from inside `OnStart()` but you can compile C# code as a .NET assembly and use that from PowerShell or just call .NET primitives from PowerShell as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813572/57428) and that way call it from the startup task.

Comment: The ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication sound like a nice way to do it.
When calling it from on start what constructor args did you specify for the ClientBuildManager?

I am not quite sure how I should get a hold of the corrects paths.

Comment: @JWendel: You can use `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager`, enumerate all `Sites`, for each of them enumerate all `Applications`, for each of them - all `VirtualDirectories` and each of those has `Path` and `PhysicalPath` - those two you can pass into `ClientBuildManager` construtor.

Comment: Great thanks! Going to try it out. For others looking for the Microsoft.Web.Administration its available as a NuGet package -  http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/.

Answer (score 0):

A start-up task is possible, but one problem with that is that the siteroot path is hardcoded and that can change.  Instead add the following to the RoleEntryPoint OnStart method:

```
 using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            string siteName = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_" + "Web";
            var siteId = serverManager.Sites[siteName].Id;
            var appVirtualDir = $"/LM/W3SVC/{siteId}/ROOT";  // Do not end this with a trailing /

            var clientBuildManager = new ClientBuildManager(appVirtualDir, null, null,
                                        new ClientBuildManagerParameter
                                        {
                                            PrecompilationFlags = PrecompilationFlags.Default,
                                        });

            clientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication();
        }
```