# Can I manually run a C# class containing a Main() method from a project that is not a console application project?

Tags: sharepoint

I am pretty new in **.NET\C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following doubt.

In my solution I have a project that should be a SharePoint job, something like this in my solution explorer:

[image]

I know that this project is deployed as a SharePoint job and it works fine.

Now I have the need to manually perform a specific operation that is in some way related to this job. So my idea was to create this **MigrateAttachments** class into this project and put a **Main()** method here, then perform only this class as a script:

```
namespace XXXMigrationJob
{
    class MigrateAttachments
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Debug.Print("MigrateAttachments Main() START");

            Debug.Print("MigrateAttachments Main() END");
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems to me that I can't perform this Main() method as a standalone method and that the only way to do it is to create a brand new **Console Application** project that will contain this class.

is it true or am I missing something and I can manually run this **MigrateAttachements** Main() method also into my XXXMigrationJob project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I run code from a .NET assembly from a command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813557/can-i-run-code-from-a-net-assembly-from-a-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't really just execute that.  It will be in a DLL not an exe. You'll need to bootstrap it somehow.

I would refactor the reusable code into a class library.  Then create a console app as you mentioned.  Reference the reusable class library and call it.

However if you don't want to create a console app, then the link NineBerry put in discusses calling .net code with PowerShell and Reflection.